# Linear Mixed Model in R: Rep. Measures, Nested, Random Effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I ran a study with the following design: Subjects were presented 100 different stimuli and asked to indicate their liking (scaled from 0-10) for each stimulus. Each stimulus was part of only one of 4 different groups, thus it was a nested design (repeated measures for the different stimulus groups; within-subjects). Now I would like to conduct a linear mixed model analysis using the `lmer` function of the `lme4` package in R, but as a newbie I am very insecure about my approach. I want to consider both random intercepts for stimuli and subjects and also allow random slopes for subjects.

I thought of the following model:

```
model = lmer(liking ~ group + (1|group/stimulus) + (1+group|subject), data=mydata)
```

Does this model make any sense?

Comment: Since your response is bounded, wouldn't it make more sense to use beta regression of score/10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as Frans Rodenburg suggested, given that you have a bounded outcome you could fit a Beta mixed effects model. In addition, I think that you could start with a random intercept for `subject` and a random intercept for `stimulus`, i.e.,

```
liking ~ group + (1 | stimulus) + (1 | subject)
```

Such a model can be fitted with the [**glmmTMB**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmmTMB) package.